# Do I need to mention policies on cookies if my site is using Amazon associates program?

Tags: privacy

I have started participating in Amazon Association program. Now, this program uses cookies while users visit my blog site. My web site as such is not using any cookies. Still some cookies are presented to the user while they are visiting my website. So, Do I need to include Policy on Cookies?  If Yes, what content shall I need to provide?

I did read the [Associates Program Operating Agreement](https://affiliate-program.amazon.in/help/operating/agreement) it is not explicitly stating about this scenario. It states following thing in its **Section-8**

> You must, however, clearly state the following on your site: “[Insert
>   your name] is a participant in the Amazon Associates Program, an
>   affiliate advertising program designed to provide a means for sites to
>   earn advertising fees by advertising and linking to amazon.in.”

But, nothing clear on cookies.

Now, If i write in my privacy policy that "MY SITE IS NOT USING ANY COOKIES", That is true but it is half true, as through advertisement cookies are used, and if I need to write about this, how I will be make sure that these cookies are not collecting any personal information?

Answer (score 1):

If your site is accessible from the EU it must not only advise that it uses cookies but give the option of turning them off.